# Añadir un entero en un array

Tags: java, array, funciones

Tengo que añadir un entero en una posición que ponga en la variable posicio, el problema es que cuando llego la posición me machaca el numero del array original y yo quiero que me lo añada en esa posición sin machacarlo y que de posición hasta el final me lo acabe rellenando.

```
package utilitats.arrays;

public class ArrayDinamic {  
     public static int [] afegirElement (int [] vector1, int element, int posicio){
         int vector2[] = new int[vector1.length+1];
            for(int i=0;i<vector1.length;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<vector2.length;j++) {
                    if(j==i && j<posicio-1)
                        vector2[i]=vector1[i];

                    if(i==j&& j==posicio-1) {
                        vector2[i]=element;
                    }
                    if( i>posicio-1) {
                        vector2[i]=vector1[i];
                    }   
                }
             }

            for(int z=0;z<vector2.length;z++) {
                System.out.println(vector2[z]);
            }
         return vector2;

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int vector1[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
        int a=12;
        int b=4;
        afegirElement(vector1,a,b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Una forma sería convertir el array `int[]` a `List<Integer>` para de esta forma usar el método add() e insertar sin problema el valor en el array, al final convertir nuevamente a  array `int[]` :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public static int[] afegirElement(int [] vector1, int element, int posicio){

      //Convierte array a lista de Integer
      List<Integer> lista = Arrays.stream(vector1)   
                            .boxed()        
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

       //Inserta elemento en posición indicada
       lista.add(posicio-1, element);
      //Convierte ArrayList a array de enteros
      int[] arrayResultante = lista.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .toArray();


    return arrayResultante;
}
```

de esta forma a partir del array inicial

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

obtendrías el array resultante:

```
[1, 3, 5, 12, 7, 9]
```

---

Si deseas realizarlo creando un arra y auxiliar, esta es una forma:

```
 public static int [] afegirElement (int [] vector1, int element, int posicio){

     //Crea array auxiliar y lo dimensiona con la longitud del array mas 1   
     int arrayAuxiliar[] = new int[vector1.length + 1];

         int counter = 0; 
         for (int i = 0; i < arrayAuxiliar.length; i++) {

             if (posicio-1 == i) {
                  //Inserta valor
                  arrayAuxiliar[i] = element; 
                  //Mueve el valor original del elemento a la siguiente posicion
                  arrayAuxiliar[i+1] = vector1[counter]; 
                  i++;
             }else{
                arrayAuxiliar[i] = vector1[counter];
             }
             counter += 1; 

         }

     return arrayAuxiliar;

 }
```

de esta forma también obtendrías el array resultante:

```
[1, 3, 5, 12, 7, 9]
```

Comment: **¿ Alguna razón por los -1 ?** ¿Tengo un error en el código?

Comment: no te lo he puesto yo, pero no me sirve usar un método externo necesito hacer un array auxiliar.

Comment: @winnie Ok. agregué la forma usando un array auxiliar. También , agregué los import de las clases que necesitas que en realidad son del SDK de java y puedes usarlos, saludos.!

Comment: Me copiaste mi respuesta -_- (lo ultimo) solo le cambiaste unos noombres

Comment: Esta seguro, de hecho me parece que tu respuesta es incorrecta , el resultado como te comentaba debe ser [1, 3, 5, 12, 7, 9] @JorgeLuis ?

Comment: Y si sale eso, de echo es igual, por que no lo ves?

Answer (score -2):

Te puse comentarios en el código

```
      public static int [] afegirElement (int [] vector1, int element, int posicio){
     int vector2[] = new int[vector1.length + 1]; // Se crea el arreglo con una posicion de más 

         int V1pos = 0; //Posición del vector1
         for (int i = 0; i < vector2.length; i++) {
             if (posicio-1 == i) { // si es la posición para insertar
                  vector2[i] = element; //Se inserta el elemento nuevo
                  vector2[i+1] = vector1[V1pos]; //Se inserta el elemento de V1 en una posición despues 
                  i += 1;
             }else{
                vector2[i] = vector1[V1pos];
             }

             V1pos += 1; //Aumentar la posición del V1 

         }

         for(int z=0;z<vector2.length;z++) {
            System.out.println(vector2[z]);
        }

     return vector2;

 }
```

La salida es

1
3
5
12
7
9

Comment: Debe de mostrarse el 7 también, de hecho se supone que ese es el problema.

Comment: Ok no te entendia muy bien ahorita lo veo

Comment: correcto, debería ser 1 3 5 12 7 9 y a mi con el programa me muestra 1 3 5 12 9 0.

Comment: Hola actualice mi respuesta.